# Leaflet with Webpack: error in css-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, leaflet

If you are trying to import Leaflet CSS within a project using Webpack

`require('leaflet/dist/leaflet.css');`

and is having this error:

`ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url-loader' in '[your-project-folder]'
 @ ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css 2:7454-7484
 @ ./~/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css
 @ ./src/components/LeafletMap/LeafletMap.js
 @ ./src/components/App/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.js`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader) correctly. You can do so explicitly within your module, with:

`require('style-loader/url!file-loader!leaflet/dist/leaflet.css');`

Or change the CSS loader to do so within webpack configuration, which would be more correct. Add this to your webpack.config.js:

`module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader/url!file-loader'
        },
        (...)
    ]
}`

Now you can leave the CSS import in your JS as usual:

`require('leaflet/dist/leaflet.css');`

Of course, make sure you have style-loader and file-loader installed:

`npm install --save-dev style-loader file-loader`